# Paypal credit card payments

Tags: paypal

When a user clicks on the buy now button, the user is taken to a page, where the user chooses the payment option. Either to pay via paypal, or to create an account an pay with credit or debit card.

Questions:

1. Is it possible for people to pay with their cards, without being forced to create a paypal account?
2. If one chooses to pay via paypal, and there is no money in the paypal account, does paypal make the payment from the attached credit or debit card?

Thank you.

Comment: How is this question related to programming?

Comment: Maybe the answer to 1 could be programmed?

Comment: My comment was referring to the first section of the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq Your queston, as stated, does not relate to programming but to how the PayPal system works.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to 1. 

Yes, if they have a Google account (gmail most likely), they can use Google checkout.

Cor you could use a credit-card payment processor like [Stripe](https://stripe.com/payments), then you can accept credit-cards directly.

You could also use Bitcoin, which would eliminate the payment-processor-parasite from the foodchain - but Bitcoin isn't popular enough as only-solution, yet.

Comment: in other words, use google checkout?

Comment: There are credit card payment gateways you can use, if you don't want to setup a merchant account with a local bank. Then you can do it without google or paypal. e.g. http://www.sagepay.com/ or eway